# IE xml parser takes out spaces

Tags: internet-explorer, xml-parsing

I've noticed that ie xml parser behaves differently from other browsers. For instance spaces in the xml document cannot stand as textnodes by themselves and are removed. Unfortunately I may have null data that is generated in the xml file. Those spaces that I've put in keeps the data from becoming null in other browsers. Is there a way to preserve these spaces in ie when using their browser? I do not want to modify the xml file itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE's behavior is correct if the elements do not have the attribute `xml:space="preserve"` set. You can simply set this attribute (on the topmost element(s) where space matters) in your document.

For more information, refer to [section 2.10 of the XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space).

Comment: That does not seem to hold (IE11) as the xml:space="preserve" attribute on my SVG tspan element with multiple space doesn't work (or IE11 is broken how it computes the bbox() of SVG.

Answer (score 1):

according MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256097.aspx

By default, Microsoft XML Core Services (MSXML) does not honor the xml:space attribute. If an application must honor the xml:space attribute, the preserveWhiteSpace property of the DOMDocument object must be set to True prior to parsing.

```
xmldoc= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.5.0");
xmldoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
xmldoc.load(url);
```